# QPainter.drawStaticText missing from PySide/PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

According to Qt's [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawStaticText) `QPainter` has a `drawStaticText` method that was added in version 4.7. However I can't use it in PySide or PyQt4, even though their respective Qt versions are newer.

`PySide.QtCore.__version__` is 4.8.5

`PyQt4.QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR` is 4.10.3

`PyQt4.QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR is 4.8.5` as well

Is it just not supported or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I was mistaken, the method is available in PyQt but not in PySide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Qt-4.7 was added in PyQt-4.8 (the versions don't necessarily stay in sync any more). A check of the PyQt-4.8 source code shows that `drawStaticText` was there from the start, and it's also there in PyQt-4.8.5. I don't have access to a PyQt-4.8.x *build* at the moment, but `drawStaticText` is definitely usable in PyQt-4.9.5 and later versions.

But the question might be not so much what version of PyQt you're using, but what version of Qt was it built against? IOW, what does the following reveal?

```
    PyQt4.QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR
```

**EDIT**:

It seems that `QPainter.drawStaticText` is not included in PySide (as of version 1.2.1), which is corroborated by [their documentation](http://seanfisk.com/pyside-docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QPainter.html). If you want to see if anything can be done about this, I would suggest you ask on the [PySide mailing list](http://lists.qt-project.org/mailman/listinfo/pyside).

Comment: QT_VERSION_STR is 4.8.5

Comment: @BoshWash. I see you've now edited your question, and your PyQt version is actually 4.10.3. I have an identical setup (Qt-4.8.5 and PyQt-4.10.3), and `QtGui.QPainter.drawStaticText` is certainly there on both Linux and WinXP. What are you doing to check whether it's there or not?

Comment: apparently I mad a mistake it is there in PyQt, but not in PySide which is strange because the use the same Version of Qt

Comment: about the method of testing, when I use it in PySide I get: `AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QPainter' object has no attribute 'drawStaticText'`

Comment: @BoshWash. I can confirm the situation with pyside-1.2.1 (see my updated answer).